# Valores recibidos por $_POST eliminan el carácter + de la cadena de texto enviada

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Resulta que por `jQuery.ajax()` paso por `data` un valor que contiene el carácter `+` varias veces. Al recibirlo con `$_POST` en el archivo PHP dichos caracteres ya no están.

Código JavaScript:

```
  var ejemplo = "esto+ es un ejem+plo";
  var postData = 'ejemplo='+ejemplo;

  $.ajax({
       url: "ejemplo.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: postData,
       success: function(data, status, xhr){
         // Els inputs de tipus cam:contacte esborraran el seu value
         $('input[tipus=camp_contacte]').val('');
         $('#btn_close').click();

       },
       error: function(jqXhr, status, errorThrown){
         console.log("POST " + status + " -> " + errorThrown);
       }
     });
```

Código PHP:

```
 $texto = $_POST['ejemplo'];
```

La variable `$texto` la guardo en una base de datos y me la inserta sin los `+`. He comprobado haciendo un `INSERT` directamente y sí me deja guardar `+`.

Es justo en el POST que los recibo sin el `+`. He comprobado también que el `ajax()`  lo envíe bien con un `console.log(postData)` y ahí también aparecen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la codificación de URLs/URIs (el que se usa también en los datos enviados en los formularios) el símbolo `+` representa un espacio en blanco. Para enviar un `+` real se debe usar la [codificación porciento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_porciento) usada en las URLs/URIs.

Si quieres enviar un símbolo más debes codificar correctamente los datos en javascript mediante el uso de, por ejemplo, [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```js
var ejemplo = "esto+ es un ejem+plo";
let postData = new URLSearchParams();
postData.append('ejemplo', ejemplo);
console.log(postData.toString());
```

El resultado es `ejemplo=esto%2B+es+un+ejem%2Bplo`. Como habrás comprobado, los símbolos `+` son codificados en entidades `%2B` que representan el código ASCII del `+`.

Si envías ese texto desde javascript a PHP verás que ahora sí que se recibe correctamente la información.

---

A continuación te muestro varias formas de enviar el contenido de la variable `ejemplo` a través de [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

### Enviando una cadena con `URLSearchParams`

Usando la explicación anterior, tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
var ejemplo = "esto+ es un ejem+plo";
let postData = new URLSearchParams();
postData.append('ejemplo', ejemplo);
$.ajax({
   url: "ejemplo.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: postData.toString(),
   /*...*/
 });
```

### Enviando directamente un formulario `FormData`

Podemos hacer uso, igualmente, de [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) en su lugar:

```
var ejemplo = "esto+ es un ejem+plo";
let postData = new FormData();
postData.append('ejemplo', ejemplo);
$.ajax({
   url: "ejemplo.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: postData,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   /*...*/
 });
```

### Envío directo

En la propiedad `data` podemos pasar como parámetro un objeto con duplas índice/valor que llegará en campos `$_POST['índice'] = valor`:

```
var ejemplo = "esto+ es un ejem+plo";
$.ajax({
   url: "ejemplo.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {
     'ejemplo': ejemplo,
   },
   /*...*/
 });
```

Debido a que el nombre de la propiedad y el nombre de la variable es el mismo, podemos omitir el nombre de la propiedad:

```
var ejemplo = "esto+ es un ejem+plo";
$.ajax({
   url: "ejemplo.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {
     ejemplo,
   },
   /*...*/
 });
```

Comment: Perfección, me has ayudado mucho gracias por tu dedicación

Comment: Ok, disculpa, no leí la última parte de tu respuesta... borrando comentario anterior. Este también lo borraré dentro de un rato para dejar limpia tu respuesta.